# Email composer plugin phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, email

I try to use the email plugin cordova. I follow the documentation on https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

I create a js like this:

```
 openDraft = function (isHtml) {

                if (isHtml && ['Win32NT', 'windows'].indexOf(device.platform) > -1) {
                    alert('Not supported on that platform!');
                    return;
                }

                cordova.plugins.email.open({
                    to: 'to@email.de',
                    cc: ['cc1@email.de', 'cc2@email.de'],
                    bcc: ['bcc1@email.de', 'bcc2@email.de'],
                    subject: isHtml ? 'Body with HTML and CSS3' : 'Body with plain text',
                    body: getBody(isHtml),
                    isHTML: isHtml
                }, showToast);
            };
```

I add on config.xml:

I write on mail .html:

```
<input type="button" onclick="openDraft.open();" value="Send mail" />
```

and i include my script.

But nothing is display.

THANKS